# Is there a difference between @property and @propertyName.settter

Tags: python, oop, properties

Recently I was dealing with properties and came across getters and setters. In most examples this kinda syntax was used

```
class ClassName():
    def __init__(self, xSize: int, ySize: int):
        self.xSize: int = xSize
        self.ySize: int = ySize

    @property
    def propertyName(self):
        return self._propertyName

    @propertyName.setter
    def propertyName(self, field: list):
        self._propertyName = field
```

My question is, is there a difference between that and this? In my code I tried both and they seemed to be working the same.

```
class ClassName():
    def __init__(self, xSize: int, ySize: int):
        self.xSize: int = xSize
        self.ySize: int = ySize

    @propertyName.getter
    def propertyName(self):
        return self._propertyName

    @playingField.setter
    def playingField(self, field: list):
        self._propertyName = field
```

Comment: The second code should produce a `NameError`, because `propertyName` isn't defined yet when you try to evaluate `propertyName.getter`.

Comment: You are correct. I think in me trying to figure out how this works I managed to somehow define the property and it magically worked. Now if I try it doesn't work and so makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first code is (mostly) equivalent (after desugaring the decorator syntax) to

```
class ClassName():
    def __init__(self, xSize: int, ySize: int):
        self.xSize: int = xSize
        self.ySize: int = ySize

    def propertyName(self):
        return self._propertyName

    propertyName = property(propertyName)

    def property_name(self, field: list):
        self._propertyName = field

    propertyName = propertyName.setter(propertyName)
```

(Decorator syntax takes care of evaluating `propertyName.setter` before the `def` statement rebinds the name, though.)

`propertyName.setter` is a method that takes a function as an argument and returns a *new* instance of `property`. When used as a decorator, it replaces the original property with the new one. It does *not* modify the existing property.

Your second code fails if you haven't yet defined `propertyName` when youu try to access `propertyName.getter`. If yours appears to work, it's because you are somehow executing it in an environment where a previous definition of `propertyName` is still in scope with an appropriate value.

There is nothing particularly magical about decorator syntax or properties. It's all straightforward function application and name binding.